# Unable to import a folder in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse

I am having the below web project structure in  eclipse kepler

```
projectA
       -Sources  --> which is a link of source folder contains java files.
       -lib      --> referenced libraries contains .jar files.
       -WebContent
           -- tiles
           -- js
           -- jsp
           -- META-INF
           -- WEBINF
```

Here webcontent is a separate folder contains jsp files.
I couldn't import the webcontent folder to my web projectA because it is in different folder so i have copied the webcontent folder into my projectA folder. But webcontent is not resolved at runtime so i am getting classnotfoundexception.

How to import webcontent folder and make the folder resolved at runtime.
Any help is appreciated.